# Диспетчеризация событий в eventEmitter

Tags: javascript, jquery, события, javascript-events

По-прежнему продолжаю разбираться с кодом сайта [Читай-город](https://www.chitai-gorod.ru/)

Среди файлов нашел `Читай-город - интернет-магазин книг_files\eventEmitter.js.Без названия` (сохраните страницу на диске)

```js
function EventEmitter(){
    var eventSubscribers = {};

    //Диспетчирезация события
    this.dispatch = function (eventName, payload){
        if(eventSubscribers.hasOwnProperty(eventName)){
            eventSubscribers[eventName].forEach(function (eventHandler){
                eventHandler(payload);
            });
        }

        return true;
    };

    //Подписка на событие. Возвращает метод отписки handler от события
    this.subscribe = function (eventName, handler){
        if(typeof handler !== 'function'){
            return;
        }

        if(!eventSubscribers.hasOwnProperty(eventName)){
            eventSubscribers[eventName] = [];
        }

        eventSubscribers[eventName].push(handler);

        return function (){
            eventSubscribers[eventName] = eventSubscribers[eventName].filter(function (currentHandler) {
                return currentHandler !== handler;
            });
        }
    }
}

window.eventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
```

Возникли вопросы:

1. Что такое диспетчерезация события?
2. И что означает

> Возвращает метод отписки handler от события

?

Особенно меня смущает

```js
this.dispatch = function (eventName, payload){
            if(eventSubscribers.hasOwnProperty(eventName)){
                eventSubscribers[eventName].forEach(function (eventHandler){
                    eventHandler(payload);
                });
            }
```

А именно цикл `forEach`, по-моему правильно было бы

```js
    this.dispatch = function (eventName, payload){
        if(eventSubscribers.hasOwnProperty(eventName)){
            eventSubscribers[eventName]=(function (eventHandler){
                eventHandler(payload);
            });
        }

        return true;
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Это просто механизм событий. Аналог обычных событий документа. Только здесь, в отличие от документа, события не привязаны к элементам документа, а работают отдельно. То же самое есть например в jQuery, например когда событие можно вызвать у любого объекта. Метод `dispatch` (аналог `element.dispatchEvent()`) вызывает событие, другими словами запускает функцию, которую ранее добавили методом `subscribe` (аналог `element.addEventListener()`).
2. После того, как подписал какую-то функцию на событие, нужно иметь возможность её отписать когда-то. Вот метод для этого. В jQuery например есть аналогичный метод `off`, а в DOM есть метод `element.removeEventListener()`.

Comment: а чему равно eventHandler при первом вызове? (это во-первых) Во-вторых, в объекте `eventSubscribers` получается несколько элементов с одним и тем же полем `eventName`.

Comment: если использовать цикл `forEach`

Comment: Ну да, там массив функций. Так часто бывает, что на один тип события много обработчиков вешается. Поэтому там `forEach`, чтобы вызвать все. А `eventHandler` - это одна из навешанных функций на это имя события.

Comment: Уточню, там не много элементов с одним полем, а это массив. Собственно он задаётся в методе subscribe - `eventSubscribers[eventName] = [];`

Comment: `var eventSubscribers = {};` - `eventSubscribers` - объект (см. 2-ю строку), а `eventSubscribers[eventName] = [];` - массив.Поэтому в `eventSubscribers` одному полю `eventName` соответствует несколько функций.

Comment: Нет. Одному полю соответствует массив. А у же в массиве его ключи ссылаются на разные функции.

Comment: а если `return function (){eventSubscribers[eventName] = eventSubscribers[eventName].filter(function (currentHandler) {return currentHandler !== handler; });}`, то в массив записываются функции, не принадлежащие текущему элементу `eventName` в объекте `eventSubscribers`.