# Подписка на событие

Tags: javascript, jquery, события, фильтрация, обработка

Разбираю сайт [Читай-город](https://www.chitai-gorod.ru/) (скачал веб-страницу полностью). Среди файлов нашел `Читай-город - интернет-магазин книг_files\eventEmitter.js.Без названия`, в котором прописывается работа с событиями

```js
function EventEmitter(){
    var eventSubscribers = {};

    //Диспетчирезация события
    this.dispatch = function (eventName, payload){
        if(eventSubscribers.hasOwnProperty(eventName)){
            eventSubscribers[eventName].forEach(function (eventHandler){
                eventHandler(payload);
            });
        }

        return true;
    };

    //Подписка на событие. Возвращает метод отписки handler от события
    this.subscribe = function (eventName, handler){
        if(typeof handler !== 'function'){
            return;
        }

        if(!eventSubscribers.hasOwnProperty(eventName)){
            eventSubscribers[eventName] = [];
        }

        eventSubscribers[eventName].push(handler);

        return function (){
            eventSubscribers[eventName] = eventSubscribers[eventName].filter(function (currentHandler) {
                return currentHandler !== handler;
            });
        }
    }
}

window.eventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
```

Судя по коду

```js
eventSubscribers[eventName].push(handler);
```

сначала в массив, соответствующий элементу-событию `eventName`, добавляется функция-обработчик `handler`, а затем

```js
        return function (){
            eventSubscribers[eventName] = eventSubscribers[eventName].filter(function (currentHandler) {
                return currentHandler !== handler;
            });
        }
```

все функции-обработчики, не совпадающие с функцией текущего вызова `handler`, записываются в массив `eventSubscribers[eventName]` и этот результат возвращается из функции `subscribe`. Тогда

1. зачем мы добавляли обработчик `handler` в массив и
2. и что должна делать функция `subscribe`?

P.S. Этот вопрос схож с [Диспетчеризация событий в eventEmitter](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1194539/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F-eventemitter-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-javascript), но это не тот же вопрос, так как там обсуждалась диспетчеризация, а здесь подписка на события.

Этот вопрос был задан, так как в других файлах, например, `Читай-город - интернет-магазин книг_files\auth.js(1).Без названия`, функция `eventEmitter.subscribe` использовалась для подписки на событие функции-обработчика, а не для отписки.

```js
eventEmitter.subscribe(popupGreeting.events.closePopup, function () {
                window.location.reload();
            });
```

Зачем вообще нужна отписка для функции-обработчика?

Comment: stackoverflow - не форум. Не редактируйте интенсивно полотно вопроса находу, потому что тогда ответы обесцениваются. И принимайте ответ, если он верен по вашему мнению или помог. Последний вопрос вы можете найти в гугле или задать отдельно. Так ваш вклад будет ценным для всех, а не только решит вашу проблему.

Comment: @PavelGrishaev Вы очень хорошо ответили на вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1194442/%d0%a1%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0-this-pop, но с последним вопросом я что-то застопорил и поэтому очень нужна ваша помощь. Ответьте на мой последний комментарий после вопроса. Вещь ведь действительно не стандартная - производится отписка, а не подписка.

Comment: ответил в ответе

Answer (score 0):

1. Мы хотели подписать обработчик на событие.
2. Эта функция подписывает обработчик на событие и возвращает **возможность** отписать обработчик от события.

Массив не обязательно должен перезаписываться, можно было например удалить из него одну функцию методом `.splice( functionIndex, 1 )`.

Я в прошлом ответе ([Диспетчеризация событий в eventEmitter](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1194539/%d0%94%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b2-eventemitter)) уже писал, что возвращаемая функция служит для отписки от события. Заметьте, что там возвращается функция, а не сразу код, отписывающий функцию. Это две разных задачи, и вторая задача отписки не обязательна. Вы её можете не вызывать если не нужно, и отписка не будет происходить. Но возможность отписки обязательна в таких системах событий. Тут она реализована как возвращаемая функция. В других библиотеках реализуется как отдельный метод, например `.unsubscribe()` или `.off()`.

Вот пример подписки и отписки:

```
// .............. тут подписка происходит ▼
let unsubscribe = eventEmitter.subscribe(popupGreeting.events.closePopup, function () {
    window.location.reload();
});

//... какие-то задачи и время проходит ...

// а тут отписка ▼
unsubscribe();
```

Метод `.subscribe()` делает всегда только одно - подписку. Но при этом даёт возможность потом отписаться. Не заставляет и не делает это, а только возвращает такую возможность. Вы можете вообще удалить эту отписку если хотите. Там она просто написана для ситуации, когда это необходимо. А отписывать события бывает необходимо. Приведу пример с DOM. Допустим, показался попап, при этом он на window повесил обработку изменения размеров окна, чтобы делать какие-то корректировки у себя. Когда попап закрылся, то обработку размеров окна нужно снять. Если не снять, то их скопится много, при очередном показе попапов, а в памяти все попапы буду храниться, потому что сборщик мусора видит, что на них ещё остались ссылки из обработчиков.

Comment: скачайте веб-страницу Читай-город (если не затруднит конечно) и посмотрите в файл Читай-город - интернет-магазин книг_files\auth.js(1).Без названия Там со 160 по 214 строку используется функция `eventEmitter.subscribe` для подписки на события, а не для отписки.

Comment: если внутри `eventEmitter.subscribe` происходит
`return function (){
        eventSubscribers[eventName] = eventSubscribers[eventName].filter(function (currentHandler) {
            return currentHandler !== handler;
            });
        }`, то это означает, что будет **точно** выполнено, а не **возможность** исполнения (оператор return) @PavelGrishaev

Comment: @ProgrammerOfParadoxThings , нет. Оператор return завершает исполнение текущего тела функции и возвращает результат. Но не делает вызов результата. Функция оттуда только возвращается, а не вызывается. Иначе не было бы никакого смысла писать там функцию и что-то возвращать, можно было бы просто исполнить код сразу.