# Отписка от или подписка на событие

Tags: javascript, jquery, события, javascript-events

Изучаю сайт [Читай-город](https://www.chitai-gorod.ru/). Файл окна входа\регистрации имеет имя `Читай-город - интернет-магазин книг_files\auth.js(1).Без названия` и следующее содержание  (отрывок со 160-й по 218-ю строчку)

```js
//подпишемся на событие при успешно отвалидированном инпуте
    eventEmitter.subscribe(gValidator.events.input.valid, function (payload){
        if(payload.input){
            payload.input.parentElement.classList.remove('error');
        }

        var formData = authFormsData[payload.form.id];
        if(formData){
            gValidator.validate(formData);
        }
    });

    //подпишемся на событие при не прошедшем валидацию инпуте
    eventEmitter.subscribe(gValidator.events.input.fail, function (payload){
        if(payload.input){
            payload.input.parentElement.classList.add('error');
        }

        var formData = authFormsData[payload.form.id];
        if(formData){
            gValidator.validate(formData);
        }
    });

    //подпишемся на событие при успешно отвалидированной формы
    eventEmitter.subscribe(gValidator.events.form.valid, function (payload){
        if(payload.submitBtn){
            payload.submitBtn.classList.remove('disabled');
        }
    });

    //подпишемся на событие при не прошедшей валидацию формы
    eventEmitter.subscribe(gValidator.events.form.fail, function (payload){
        if(payload.submitBtn){
            payload.submitBtn.classList.add('disabled');
        }
    });

    //подпишемся на событие успешного сброса пароля
    eventEmitter.subscribe(auth.events.resetPassSuccess, function (){
        //Popup.hideAll();
        var resetPassMessage = Popup.getInstance('resetPassMessage', '.js__popup_reset_pass_message', getResetPassMessage());
        resetPassMessage.show();
    });

    eventEmitter.subscribe(auth.events.registrationSuccess, function (){
        if(window.version === 'd'){
            window.location.reload();
        } else if (window.version === 'm') {
            //Popup.hideAll();
            var popupGreeting = Popup.getInstance('greeting', '.js__popup_greeting');
            //покажем попап приветствия
            popupGreeting.show();

            eventEmitter.subscribe(popupGreeting.events.closePopup, function () {
                window.location.reload();
            });
        }
    });
```

Из [Подписка на событие](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1194807/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5) следует, что `eventEmitter.subscribe` производит отписку обработчика от события, но такое ощущение, что наоборот - производится подписка. Проясните каким образом происходит работа оператора `eventEmmitter.subscribe` в приведенном файле и для чего нужна отписка, если такая производится.

Comment: subscribe это подписка

Comment: это библиотека rxjs для реактивного программирования - https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/overview. По типу промисов в чистом JS - https://learn.javascript.ru/promise-basics

Comment: Вы неверно меня поняли в прошлом вопросе. Читайте внимательно или немного на другие вещи акцент делайте, не знаю :)

Comment: subscribe это шаблон проектирования, rxjs это лишь частная реализация. Тут его нет